# Show that the piecewise defined function is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am faced with the following problem:

Determine whether the following function is continous, once differentiable, or twice differentiable:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3+x-1 &\text{if $x \leq 0$;} \\
x^3-x-1 &\text{if $x >0$}. \end{cases}$

So far, I have shown that $f$ is not once differentiable at $x = 0$, and since $C^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \subset C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, it is also not twice differentiable.

What I am having a little bit of difficulty with is showing that it is continuous at $x = 0$.  Here is what I've done so far: since each piece of the piecewise defined function is continuous on its domain of definition, all I need to do is check the point $x = 0$.

- For $x > 0$, I want to see if the right-hand limit exists. In this case, $|f(x) - f(0)| = |x^{3}-x-1 - (0^{3} + 0 - 1)| = |x^{3} - x| = |x(x^{2}-1)| = |x||x^{2}-1|$.

Now, if $|x|<1$, then $|x^{2} - 1| = |x+1||x-1| \leq (|x|+1)(|x|+1) = 2(|x|+1)< 2(1+1) = 4$.

So, I have that $|x||x^{2}-1|<4|x| < \epsilon$ if we take $|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Therefore, I take $\displaystyle \delta = \min\left\{ 1, \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right\}$, and I have $\forall \epsilon > 0$ that $|f(x) - f(0)|<\epsilon$; i.e., the right-hand limit exists and is equal to $-1$.

- For $x < 0$, I want to see if the left-hand limit exists.  In this case, $|f(x) - f(0)| = |x^{3}+x-1 - (0^{3}+0-1)| = |x^{3}+x-1+1| = |x^{3} + x| \leq |x^{3}| + |x|$.

If $|x|<1$, then $|x^{3}|<|x|$.

So, I have that $|x^{3}|+|x| < |x| + |x| = 2|x| < \epsilon$ provided we take $\displaystyle |x| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore, I take $\delta = \min \left\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}$, and I have  $\forall \epsilon > 0$ that $|f(x) - f(0)|<\epsilon$; i.e., the left-hand limit exists and is equal to $-1$.

Thus, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = -1$, and since $f(0) = -1$, we have that $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$.  Thus, it is continuous $\forall \mathbb{R}$.

I suppose what I would like to know is if I showed this correctly and, if not, how I might fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: perfect!   VVVVVVVV

Comment: Looks flawless $\\\\$

Comment: Awesome!! So glad to hear that. I was second-guessing what I did for the left-hand limit.

Comment: It is good to use $\epsilon \text{-} \delta$ definition of limit, but if you are not asked particular to show using that definition, then I think you can directly compute the left and right hand limit, and you can show it is continuous. Lastly, you have done a good job. Cheers!!

Comment: I suppose also I could have shown each piece of f was differentiable on its domain of definition, and then that would have implied it was continuous there?

Comment: When does the below method not work? What flaw is it prone to that the $\epsilon-\delta$ method is not?

Left hand limit = $(0)^3+(0)-1=-1$ and right hand limit = $(0)^3-(0)-1=-1$. Also, $f(0)=(0)^3+(0)-1=-1$.

Since, Left hand limit=f(0)=right hand limit, we conclude that $f$ is continuous at x=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** For any $x$ such that $|x|<1$ implies that $$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq |x^{3}| + |x| \leq 2|x|$$
and provide to take $|x|\leq \epsilon/2$ is enough.